# Seeking Clarification on the Terminology Used in Spinoza and Locke's Epistemologies

Tags: epistemology, consciousness, spinoza, locke, human-nature

I'm currently studying the works of Spinoza and Locke and I'm struggling to fully comprehend their respective epistemologies. Specifically, I'm trying to understand the relationship between Spinoza's definition of humans as modes of substance that are conscious of themselves as endeavoring/desiring and Locke's discussions on consciousness and the differences between "human" and "personhood."

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this topic or provide any comparisons of the terminologies used in their discussions. I've been working on a different thesis for a while now, and returning to this topic late at night has made all the terminology seem a bit blurry again.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!